# Android Highlight card as dialog modal inside recyclerview on click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialog, android-cardview

I'm trying to implement a custom behavior in a card click inside of a `RecyclerView`, what I want to accomplish is to animate the selected Item layout by expanding and adding a fab on top of it, while dimming the screen behind. My current approach is to call notifyItemChanged on item click and when bindViewHolder method gets called, I'm adding the fab, as the item layout root have the animateLayoutChanges property set to true, the item is expanding finely, but I couldn't manage to dim the screen behind the card, like if the card were a dialog, I also want that a click outside the card to dismiss all the changes, is there any other way to accomplish this?

[image: description example]

Comment: you can create the custom fab dialog, or you can have the fab layout match_parent with background color